# select entire (but filtered) column in rowwise calculation (Dplyr)

Tags: r, dplyr

What would be the correct Dplyr pipeline for the following base calculation?

```
dat      <- data.frame(a = 0:10, b = 0:10, c = 0:10)
dat$d    <- apply(dat, 1, sum)
ind      <- dat$d>quantile(dat$d[dat$d>0], 0.1)
```

I tried (but failed):

```
ind      <- tibble(dat) %>% rowwise() %>% 
               mutate(d = sum(c_across(a:c)), ind = d>quantile(select_var(d>0), 0.1)) %>%
               pull(ind)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tibble(dat) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(
    d = sum(c(a, b, c)),
    ind = d > quantile(dat %>% filter(d >0) %>% pull(d), 0.1)
  ) %>%
  pull(ind)
```

Gives the same values as your `ind`.  The slight difficulty is due to the fact that you are calculating quantiles based on a subset of your data frame rather than on its entirity.

Answer (score 1):

This you can do using `.$` so that `quantile` is returned for whole of the data

```
dat %>% rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(d = sum(c_across(a:c))) %>% 
  mutate(ind = d > quantile(.$d[.$d >0], 0.1))

    a  b  c  d   ind
1   0  0  0  0 FALSE
2   1  1  1  3 FALSE
3   2  2  2  6  TRUE
4   3  3  3  9  TRUE
5   4  4  4 12  TRUE
6   5  5  5 15  TRUE
7   6  6  6 18  TRUE
8   7  7  7 21  TRUE
9   8  8  8 24  TRUE
10  9  9  9 27  TRUE
11 10 10 10 30  TRUE
```

Check that without adding `.$` before `d` it gets undesired results

```
dat %>% rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(d = sum(c_across(a:c))) %>% 
  mutate(ind = d > quantile(d[d >0], 0.1))

# A tibble: 11 x 5
# Rowwise: 
       a     b     c     d ind  
   <int> <int> <int> <int> <lgl>
 1     0     0     0     0 NA   
 2     1     1     1     3 FALSE
 3     2     2     2     6 FALSE
 4     3     3     3     9 FALSE
 5     4     4     4    12 FALSE
 6     5     5     5    15 FALSE
 7     6     6     6    18 FALSE
 8     7     7     7    21 FALSE
 9     8     8     8    24 FALSE
10     9     9     9    27 FALSE
11    10    10    10    30 FALSE
```